# Pre-process data with multiple instances against 1 label for neural network tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm training a neural network to predict the number of fan growth of a Facebook page based on the no of posts, the category of post(video, link,status etc) and number of shares ,like & comments for each post. So, there is a single label against multiple instances as label(fan_growth) is being calculated for each day(not for each post):
[image]

So If i use one hot encoding for categorical data: 
[image]

here date,day,link,video,status,reactions,comments and shares are features, while fan_growth is label. How can I use single label against more than 1 instance? As using '100' again all 1st 3 instances would not be correct.

Comment: can you clearly state what your x and your y is? do you want to predict fan_growth with day, link, video, status, reactions, comments and shares? why wouldn't it be possible to do this classification with those features?

Comment: @dv3 yes I have to predict fan_growth each day based on all posts on that day. Problem is that I don't have label against each example. For example, if there are 10 posts in one day, there would be singal label(fan growth on that day) against 10 examples.

Comment: now it makes more sense, but I'm the wrong one to help you, I would actually train the model on the second chart you provided

Comment: Have you thought of using LSTM's?

Comment: @ThomasW I didn't know about LSTM, just gone through now, but I haven't found it much relevant. My problem here is that I have data that contains both categorical and continuous data, I want to apply OneHot encoding on just 1 column of my data and use others as it is. Is that possible?

Comment: @ThomasW if you ignore the second image and just see first, I want to use OneHotEncoder for 'type' column while I want to read other columns directly.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, basically you have a variable number of events that can occur in a given day (posted a video, link, or status zero or more times each), and for each of these you have the associated reactions, comments, and shares. Then you want to predict the fan growth per day based on this variable number of actions taken in a single day. Please correct me if I am wrong.

What you can do is train a recurrent neural network on variable-length sequences of data. You would structure your input data as:

```
x_ij = [category, reactions, comments, shares]_i for day j
i = 1, 2, ..., n_j (number of posts in day "j")
j = 1, 2, ..., N (number of days in dataset)
```

You can think of each `x_ij` as a time step in day `j`. Then the full input sequence for a single day would look like:

```
X_j = [x_1j, x_2j, ..., x_nj]
```

And your output vector would be `Y = [y_1, y_2, ..., y_N]` where each `y_j` is the fan growth for day `j`. Basically the training process then involves setting up your recurrent neural network using `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` and using the `sequence_length` to specify how long each input sequence is. It would look something like this (there are going to be a lot of implementation details that I will skip here):

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_hidden)
# Any additional things like tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper you want here
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(cell, 1)  # only one output number, right?
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, sequence_length=sequence_length)
```

Note that I use [GRU cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit) here ([TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/GRUCell)) instead of [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) ([TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell)). This is partly preference, but basically GRU can do everything LSTM can but is more efficient. You will run your training process then, passing batches of data of size `[batch_size, num_steps_per_day, num_features]`, and a `sequence_length` tensor of size `[batch_size, 1]` that gives the number of steps per day. Something like:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    shuffle_training_set()
    for batch in range(num_batches):
      d = get_next_batch()
      t = get_next_target_batch()
      s = # length of each data sample in your batch
      sess.run(optimize, feed_dict={data: d, targets: t, sequence_length: s})
      # periodically validate and stop when you stop improving
```

Here, `optimize` might be defined something like:

```
cost = # your cost function here...
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()  # I usually have luck with this optimizer
optimize = optimizer.minimize(cost)
```

Check out [this excellent example](https://gist.github.com/danijar/d11c77c5565482e965d1919291044470) (not my content) to get you started on some of the implementation details. This example is showing sequence labeling, but it should be fairly simple to modify it to predict fan growth instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that RNN should be apply per day in that case.

You could simply sum all the information on 1 day?

For example:
[image]

you could have:

```
{1st row: {day:1,
        link: 2,
        video: 1,
        status: 0,
        reactions: 489+964+964,
        comments: 0,
        shares: 0},
 2nd row: {day: 3,
        link:1,
        video: 1,
        status: 0,
        reactions: 685,
        comments: 0,
        shares: 0}}
```

What is possible with RNN would be to see each day as a sequence and see how things evolve through time.